# Refresh database's data

Tags: c#, database, winforms, ms-access, refresh

How can I refresh the data from my database (ms access) in c# using windows form application? Part of the code where I insert the data:

```
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID_uporabnika", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(textBox6.Text);
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@datum", OleDbType.DBDate).Value = DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@ID_zivila", OleDbType.Integer).Value = Convert.ToInt32(iDTextBox.Text);
insertCommand.Parameters.Add("@skupaj_kalorij", OleDbType.Double).Value = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
empConnection.Open();

try
    {
        int count = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
catch (OleDbException ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
finally
    {
         empConnection.Close();
         MessageBox.Show("zauižiti obrok je bil shranjen");
         textBox1.Clear();
         textBox2.Clear();
         textBox3.Clear();
         textBox4.Clear();
         textBox5.Clear();
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? There's too many ways to refresh a database, so it would help to know what exactly you're trying to do here...

Comment: Well, i have several forms to insert different data to my database. And i just wan't to  use the new data after i have inserted it in the database without closing the whole aplication.

Comment: @Simon: Refresh the data *where*? Do you mean to refresh your controls with updated data from the database after you update some data in it? Please be a bit more specific, a long but clear question rarely hurts.

Comment: Am... i don't really now how else to say it. I wan't to refresh my whole database. Nothing else. At the next form load i must have the new data available to use.

Comment: How are you accessing the database? Are you loading information from the DB and then disconnecting the db object?

Comment: What is your database then? Your application (since you are referring to a Form load) or the database (MS Access)? The latter does not need to be refreshed, and the first one is not actually a database. Or are you actually asking how you update values in the database?

Comment: i wrote it on the question that it is a ms access database. And when i put some data in it, i still can't use that data right away. I have to restart the aplication and than the new data is available to use. And now i want to do the refresh while the aplication is running.

Comment: @Simon: I know you wrote MS Access in your question, that wasn't what I was asking. It makes no sense to refresh a database. When you want data from the database you create a new SqlConnection, or in your case an `OleDbConnection` and get a `DataReader` from it by calling `ExecuteReader`. The new data *should* be in your DataReader, is that not the case?

Comment: Nobody knows what you mean by "refresh"

Comment: ... To make the new data should be useable without restarting the aplication and stored in the database

Comment: I believe you have not told us, that you are using the freshly insered data on your form. Once you insert a new record, it does not apear, before you reload the form. Correct so far? So please show us, where you use the data to populate any win form controls. That way people will be able to provide you with the correct method/code to refresh your form, not the database.

Answer (score 0):

right after you do the insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(), bind the data from the database. not sure what you want to populate again though.

```
try
{
    int count = insertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();

    // do your getting of data here
    // use datareaders to populate your objects
}
catch (OleDbException ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    empConnection.Close();
     MessageBox.Show("zauižiti obrok je bil shranjen");
     textBox1.Clear();
     textBox2.Clear();
     textBox3.Clear();
     textBox4.Clear();
     textBox5.Clear();
}
```